# Selection set cleared after command when using UsePickSet

Tags: c#, autocad

I have to run a command with a preselected set of polylines. I use the UsePickSet because of this.

After the command, I need to indicate to the user by hilighting/selecting a smaller set of filtered polylines. I add these to the selectionset after processing.

However, looks like, if we mention CommandFlags.UsePickSet in the method attributes, then, it automatically clears the selection set when the command ends, even if its changed.

Any way to get past this?

I made a POC if anyone wants to try out. The SetACADHandleSelection1 will retain the selection, while the SetACADHandleSelection2 will not.

```
    [CommandMethod("GetACADHandle", CommandFlags.UsePickSet)]
    public static void GetACADHandle()
    {
        Editor ed = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;

        PromptSelectionResult res = ed.SelectImplied();
        if (res.Status != PromptStatus.Error)
        {
            var pline = res.Value[0].ObjectId;

            ed.WriteMessage(pline.Handle.ToString());

            // SetACADHandleSelection(pline.Handle.ToString());
        }
    }



    [CommandMethod("SetACADHandleSelection1")]
    public static void SetACADHandleSelection1(string handle)
    {
        Editor ed = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
        Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Database db = doc.Database;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(handle))
        {
            PromptResult res = ed.GetString("Enter acad Handle");

            if (res.Status != PromptStatus.Error)
            {
                handle = res.StringResult;
            }

        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(handle))
        {

            using (Transaction Tx = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
            {
                Handle handlep = new Handle(Convert.ToInt64(handle, 16));
                ObjectId objId = db.GetObjectId(false, handlep, 0);

                ed.SetImpliedSelection(new ObjectId[] { objId });
            }
        }
    }


    [CommandMethod("SetACADHandleSelection2", CommandFlags.UsePickSet)]
    public static void SetACADHandleSelection2(string handle)
    {
        Editor ed = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
        Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Database db = doc.Database;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(handle))
        {
            PromptResult res = ed.GetString("Enter acad Handle");

            if (res.Status != PromptStatus.Error)
            {
                handle = res.StringResult;
            }

        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(handle))
        {

            using (Transaction Tx = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
            {
                Handle handlep = new Handle(Convert.ToInt64(handle, 16));
                ObjectId objId = db.GetObjectId(false, handlep, 0);

                ed.SetImpliedSelection(new ObjectId[] { objId });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

try to use CommandFlags.Redraw
for more info visit:
https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-electrical/getting-started/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-NET/files/GUID-F77E8FE0-8034-4704-93BD-F717608F8223-htm.html